# Why does Cross_Val_Score Differ so much from Stratified Shuffle Split?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to cross validate my score using scikit-learn and I'm running into a weird issue where "manually" created a Stratified Shuffle Loop performs much better than using the inbuilt cross_val_score.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cPickle

import helper_functions

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit

from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

rf_clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=5)

with open("../../stashed_dims.pkl", 'rb') as fout:
    [TRAIN_X, TRAIN_Y, TEST_X, test_index] = cPickle.load(fout)


N_CV = 1
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(TRAIN_Y, N_CV, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

for iterations, [local_train_index, local_test_index] in enumerate(sss):
    X_train, X_test = TRAIN_X[local_train_index], TRAIN_X[local_test_index]
    y_train, y_test = TRAIN_Y[local_train_index], TRAIN_Y[local_test_index]

    rf_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    pred = rf_clf.predict(X_test)

    print("Stratified Shuffle Split method 1")
    print(helper_functions.get_score(pred, y_test))

scorer = make_scorer(helper_functions.get_score)
scores = cross_val_score(rf_clf, TRAIN_X, TRAIN_Y, cv = sss, scoring = scorer, verbose = 10)
print("Stratified Shuffle Split method 2")
print(scores)
```

[image: Screenshot]

I'm at a loss what the difference between these two methods is. Any ideas?

[StratifiedShuffleSplit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit)
[cross_val_score documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html)

Comment: Good luck with finding the problem!

Comment: Ami, you were right. I needed to follow the convention of self._score_func(y_true, y_pred)

Comment: Oh, I shall undelete my answer, then. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without the full code (which is not given), but, at least from this code, it does not appear that you are using the same scoring function.

explicit:

```
print(helper_functions.get_score(pred, y_test))
```

implicit:

```
scores = cross_val_score(... scoring = scorer ...)
```

Comment: I created a scorer as follows, scorer = make_scorer(helper_functions.get_score). Shouldn't this be functionally the same? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I could not know this from the question. I'll delete this answer later on, as it's irrelevant.

Comment: I appreciate the help Ami!

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in that order matters for my scoring function.

foo(y_true, y_pred) != foo(y_pred, y_true) for this scoring function.